# How to switch DBeaver language from german to english?

Tags: language, dbeaver

i installed DBeaver as a portable app from [portapps](https://portapps.io/app/dbeaver-portable/)

I choosed german but want to switch to english.

I am aware that its a parameter, but how to do in Windows10?

Thanks,

Anton

I guess its something in c:\portapps\dbeaver-portable\app\dbeaver.ini

Answer (score 3):

I found in Fenster, Einstellungen, Sprache

Englisch

which modifies the dbeaver.ini in this way:

> -startup
>   plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.600.v20191014-2022.jar
>   --launcher.library
>   plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.1100.v20190907-0426
>   **-nl**
>   **en**
>   -vmargs
>   -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions
>   --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
>   -Xms64m
>   -Xmx1024m

Answer (score 3):

In case you have a user installation, please check first StartMenu Link to DBeaver:

C:\Users<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\DBeaver Community\DBeaver

Link `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\DBeaver\dbeaver.exe -nl de`
needs to be changed to
Link `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\DBeaver\dbeaver.exe -nl en`

Answer (score 0):

In Version 21.3.3: Fenster - Einstellungen - User interface - Sprache

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).